# Can we use "it" to refer to "something"?

Tags: reference

Can we use "it" to refer to "something" in the following sentence or should we say "that thing"?

> It's a disapproving yet humorous thing to say when someone does
> **something** very strange and pointless, especially when **it**'s elaborate.

Comment: Did you look up the word 'it' in a dictionary? Cambridge Dictionary is a good one, and it's available online.

Comment: Sure, why not?  What's the source of this quote, please?

Comment: @James K Thank you. Actually, I wrote that sentence.

Comment: @Mohammad This isn’t meant to be snarky, but that is the functional purpose of the word “it” as a pronoun. The way you have described it (haha) is really the only way it’s meant to be used.

Answer (score 1):

That's very common.

> I ate something.  It was hot and spicy.